# Spatial index on geometry column and not NULL column impossible

Tags: mysql, indexing, geospatial, mysql-5.7

From the mysql doc

> A geometry column should be NOT NULL, but a geometry column cannot have DEFAULT values

So problem comes when I want to add a spatial index, ALL part of spatial index must be not null and if I tick NULL I have to put a DEFAULT VALUE that gave me the first error.

I'm using mysql 5.7, innodb column, here is what I've done to reproduce the problem:

```
my origin table geotest3:
id MEDIUMINT
lat DECIMAL
lon DECIMAL
```

I've added a geom column:

```
alter table geotest3 add geom geometry;
```

Next I fill the column with lat lon data:

```
UPDATE geotest3 
  SET geom = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',geotest3.lon,' ',geotest3.lat,')'));
```

Now I cannot add a spatial index on geom column for problem explained above.

I don't know if its a bug or if I missed something.

Comment: I guess pb mean problem? Dont use chat speak to describe your question. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot one step (3.)
The whole procedure should be :

1. Create you geometry column allowing null values (ok)
   `alter table geotest3 add geom geometry;`
2. Fill you column (ok)
   `UPDATE geotest3 
   SET geom = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',geotest3.lon,' ',geotest3.lat,')'));`
3. Now the column doesn't contain null value anymore, so you can make it not null and add the spatial index (missing step)

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `geotest3` 
   CHANGE COLUMN `geom` `geom` GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
   ADD SPATIAL INDEX `geom_SPATIAL` (`geom` ASC);
   ```

Comment: thx, this is working  with your way but strangly if you add a fourth step this will not .. for me if i make the column NOT NULL as step 3 and add spatial index as step 4 , it doesn't work anymore, don't know why ..